# Specifics of parameters within find method

Tags: c#, list

I recently was introduced to the `find` method for lists vs the `Foreach` loop. I was hoping for clarification as to what a part of the statement means. Consider the following:

```
CartItem Item = Items.Find(c => c.ProductID == ProductID) && c.ProductName == "ABS001");
```

- CartItem: The type of an item in the list
- Item: Local variable to store the matching product
- Items: The list in which is to be searched

What I don't understand is the presence of "c =>". In a Foreach loop you would define just a local variable for the method as "c" and in the parameters that follow it seems to be used as such but what does the "=>" mean or do? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I don't understand is the presence of "c =>".

It's the lambda operator, used in [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx). It's a compact way of specifying a delegate (or expression tree) - in this case used as a predicate, applied to each item in the list until it return `true` (at which point that item is returned).

Note that currently your code is invalid, as you've got an extra bracket instead of a `D` (at a guess) - it should be:

```
CartItem Item = Items.Find(c => c.ProductID == ProductID && c.ProductName == "ABS001");
```

It's worth getting familiar with lambda expressions, as they're incredibly useful - particularly as part of [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx), which is the more modern way of finding items, transforming sequences etc. For example, you could use:

```
CartItem Item = Items.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ProductID == ProductID && c.ProductName == "ABS001");
```

Or find *all* items:

```
IEnumerable<Item> matches = Items.Where(c => c.ProductID == ProductID && c.ProductName == "ABS001");
```

(There's much more to LINQ than this - it's worth reading up on.)

Comment: Thank you for the link. If I understand this correctly the c then becomes the parameter to which all following parameters are tested against? In this case c is a temp variable for each index item in the list of Items and as such has access to the fields within the list? Because I have a list of items it just knows that "c" then will be each object stored in the list as it does it's search?

Comment: @TargetofGravity: `c` is the parameter for the lambda expression. The body of the lambda expression is invoked once per item, with `c` as the "current" item. I don't know how much you understand about delegates already, but it's worth being clear about that before anything else. Then understand that lambda expressions make it easy to create delegates.

Comment: thank you. That is starting to make sense, new to the concept.